# How do I export a .dae file from .pmx with textures baked?

Tags: mesh, texturing, export

I am using Blender version 2.92.0 and I’m trying to export a .pmx file to a .dae file. I’ve downloaded a file on Internet and it comes with a .pmx file and two image files both in .png format. My goal is to export the .dae file so it includes all the image textures (in other words, baked).I want my target file be like the other .dae files I've got:[image]

I tried applying the image textures on the .pmx mesh (MESH ONLY) in Blender and export it via the Blender exporter. This is what I did:[image]

Everything looks fine in Blender. However, when I reviewed the exported .dae file, it does not have any textures. Puzzling thing is that I also attempted to export it as .usdz format but there is no textures either, even though I did check the “bake textures” box.

Does anybody know what to do? Or not I'll have to edit the raw file code manually (Worst case scenario)

Answer (score 0):

Your material should be setup using the default Principled BSDF node like this (in the Shader editor)

[image: Image Texture node connected to Base Color of Principled BSDF]

Not just for .dae, this will work for most exporters.

Comment: Thanks to your help, it works. However, I would like to ask why when I review it in Finder it doesn't show anything? Is this normal?

Comment: What is Finder?

Comment: It is like File Explorer on Windows but Finder is for Mac. The interface is like the first picture above. A preview of the model is supposed to appear on the right side when the .dae file is clicked. The problem here is that a preview doesn't show even though it does contain the data.