# .collada file does not contain reference to texture

Tags: export, collada

I am new to blender and I am working to create a simple plane with some texture.

For the work I do I need to export a Collada file from blender and then import it into a target software.

If I open with a text editor the .collada file from blender, I don't see any reference to the textures file I used. Therefore, my target software does not import any texture. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: What do your shader nodes look like?

Comment: I have diffuse, bump, glossy nodes applied. All of them "come from" a different texture file (.png)

Comment: Hi is your texture in the same file as your dae file? I recently had to use dae to export from blender to sketchup and I used dae like this... I had a folder where I had my texture and blend file, I exported it to dae and dae knew that texture is in this same folder and sketchup opened it with texture loaded, do you have it in same folder?

Comment: I think I might have found the issue. You need to apply a texture through a material for the blender collada exporter to recognize it. :( 

@MikoCG, my texture files are in the same folder.

Comment: This is the answer that I am talking about
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/4900/68015

Comment: A node setup like [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/230459/88681) should export.